# Far jump in ntdll.dll's internal ZwCreateUserProcess

Tags: winapi, assembly, process

I'm trying to understand how the Windows API creates processes so I can create a program to determine where invalid exes fail. I have a program that calls `kernel32.CreateProcessA`. Following along in OllyDbg, this calls `kernel32.CreateProcessInternalA`, which calls `kernel32.CreateProcessInternalW`, which calls `ntdll.ZwCreateUserProcess`. This function goes:

```
mov eax, 0xAA
xor ecx, ecx
lea edx, dword ptr [esp+4]
call dword ptr fs:[0xC0]
add esp, 4
retn 0x2C
```

So I follow the call to `fs:[0xC0]`, which contains a single instruction:

```
jmp far 0x33:0x74BE271E
```

But when I step this instruction, Olly just comes back to `ntdll.ZwCreateUserProcess` at the `add esp, 4` right after the call (which is not at `0x74BE271E`). I put a breakpoint at `retn 0x2C`, and I find that the new process was somehow created during the execution of `add esp, 4`.

So I'm assuming there's some magic involved in the far jump. I tried to change the CS register to `0x33` and EIP to `0x74BE271E` instead of actually executing the far jump, but that just gave me an access violation after a few instructions. What's going on here? I need to be able to delve deeper beyond the abstraction of this `ZwCreateUserProcess` to figure out how exactly Windows creates processes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
jmp far 0x33:0x74BE271E`
```

That jump is entering the kernel. `0x33` is a special segment selector that points to some kind of x86 gate; this triggers a context switch into the kernel.

Answer (score 6):

Actually, that jump does not enter the kernel but switches to the x64 usermode subsystem of WoW64 (Win32 on Win64).

The selector 33h is a special selector that covers the 4GB memory space but is set to x64 mode. The jump goes to the 64-bit (but still usermode) part of wow64cpu.dll, which converts 32-bit API parameters to 64-bit ones and call the API in 64-bit ntdll.dll (yes, you have two of them in a WoW64 process). That ntdll, in turn, calls the real system call which goes to the kernel.

Here's a few links that describe the mechanism in more detail. You can also find more by searching for the term "heaven's gate".

http://rce.co/knockin-on-heavens-gate-dynamic-processor-mode-switching/

http://wasntnate.com/2012/04/heavens-gate-64-bit-code-in-32-bit-file/

Answer (score 4):

The part you are missing is the kernel part.  You'll want to attach a kernel mode debugger and step into the kernel side code of ZwCreateUserProcess to see how the process is created.  You should also take a look at Chapter 5 "Processes, Threads, and Jobs" of Windows Internals 5th or 6th edition.  That chapter covers process creation in detail.